# How do I buy raw filters that are the same kind as used in dryers?

Tags: dryer, filter

Do you know the kind of filter net in your dryer filters?

[image]

The filter material is dense enough to block any lint from passing through, but airy enough to not block any of the air pressure.

I'd like to buy a raw sheet of this kind of filter to build something. I have no idea how to even search for that. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: AFIK the screen part of a dryer filter is not readily available in sheets. This screen does not screen out all the lint, far from it. A lot of lint ends up in the dryer vent and this must be cleaned out periodically.

Comment: "Screen door screen" or "wire mesh" might be good search terms. I'm not sure exactly your desired outcome, but screen door material may work for you.

Answer (score 2):

My dryer its just a metal screen.  Wire mesh also would be a name to ask for.